# How do you mark DAG run as success when majority of tasks succeed, and only a few fail?

Tags: python, airflow

I have a DAG that runs hundreds of tasks.  There are tasks that if they fail the failures are handled elsewhere, so it is ok if they fail.  However, Airflow marks the whole DAG run as a failure.

What I want to do is as follows:  I want to measure the number of tasks and if more than a certain percentage succeed mark the DAG run as a success.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by defining Airflow trigger rule:

all_done: all parents are done with their execution

```py
op = DummyOperator(task_id='join', dag=dag, trigger_rule='all_done')
```

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules